# PowerPoint 2013: Arrow Symbol Before Each New Line of Text

Tags: powerpoint, powerpoint-2013

I have looked everywhere and can't figure this one out. I'm not even sure what to call this symbol. I thought (think) it is a new line symbol, but can't seem to find an answer.

There is a little arrow before each new line in my text boxes in PowerPoint 2013. It is very small, but very noticeable. I tried to attach a picture, but just signed up and don't have the reputation points. I will work on that if no one can answer (but I believe in you). Thanks!

Comment: you could still give a link to an image representing what you are talking about, from google images or from something like http://postimage.org/

Comment: Thanks, Victor! Here is a picture of it. http://postimg.org/image/93eaha4r7/

Comment: Hey, I figured it out on my own actually. This has been a problem for weeks and guess what. It is a custom bullet resized to 25% of text size. Yeahhhh. Sorry.

Comment: You should post that as answer yourself :-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own actually. This has been a problem for weeks and guess what. It is a custom bullet re-sized to 25% of text size.